# How do I get the fully-automatic fire for the Fazertron?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

I am just curious as to which garrison in *Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon* is the quest to get the full-auto upgrade on the Fazertron assault rifle found? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the [Fazertron](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Fazertron)?

Answer (score 3):

The Fazertron's full-auto upgrade is unlocked after the ["Ruining Everything" hostage rescue mission in garrison # 8](http://guides.gamepressure.com/farcry3blooddragon/guide.asp?ID=19714), and costs $2000.

<sup>Sources:

 ["Fazertron", IGN Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3-blood-dragon/Fazertron)

["Ruining Everything" Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon Game Guide | gamepressure.com](http://guides.gamepressure.com/farcry3blooddragon/guide.asp?ID=19714)</sup>